# Non-existent service in FOSUserBundle's controller override

Tags: symfony, controller, overriding, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override FOSUserBundle's `RegistrationController`. I've followed [the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) and could get Symfony to use my controller instead, but I am getting this error when its `registerAction` method is called:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.registration.form"
```

I modified the `DependencyInjection\Configuration` class to match the original one but the services don't seem to be added. FOSUserBundle's documentation doesn't say anything about this, so I don't know how to set it up properly.

Here are my files:

**RegistrationController.php**

```
namespace ACME\AuthBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
  public function registerAction(Request $request)
  {
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form'); // Source of error
    ...
  }
}
```

**Configuration.php**

```
namespace ACME\AuthBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('fos_user');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('registration')
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->canBeUnset()
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode('confirmation')
                            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                            ->children()
                                ->booleanNode('enabled')->defaultFalse()->end()
                                ->scalarNode('template')->defaultValue('FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig')->end()
                                ->arrayNode('from_email')
                                    ->canBeUnset()
                                    ->children()
                                        ->scalarNode('address')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                                        ->scalarNode('sender_name')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                        ->arrayNode('form')
                            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                            ->children()
                                ->scalarNode('type')->defaultValue('fos_user_registration')->end()
                                ->scalarNode('name')->defaultValue('fos_user_registration_form')->end()
                                ->arrayNode('validation_groups')
                                    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                                    ->defaultValue(array('Registration', 'Default'))
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have activated FOSUserBundle in app/AppKernel.php and is this service available in app/console container:debug?

Comment: Yes, FOSUserBundle is activated. The specific `fos_user.registration.form` isn't listed in `container:debug`, although there are subservices such as `fos_user.registration.form.factory`. Trying to use them work, so how can I add the one I need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOSUserBundle uses a form factory to create the form so you would need to use..

```
/** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
$formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');

$form = $formFactory->createForm();
```

Comment: That did the trick to create the form. How can I add new services to the controller, if I need to use `fos_user.registration.form.handler` for example ?

Comment: There are a few parts to it (services files, creating classes, etc) but they are all in the documentation and it explains it a hell of a lot better than I could - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html